# No DisplayPort output via DisplayPort→HDMI adapter from Nvidia card using Linux on Thinkpad W520

Tags: linux, hdmi, displayport, adapter, nvidia-quadro

I have a Thinkpad W520 laptop with Nvidia Quadro 1000M graphics running Debian testing (“wheezy”) and Nvidia driver version 295.40-1. The graphics mode is set to discrete in the BIOS. I would like to use the DisplayPort to connect to a HDMI monitor. The display driver does not recognize that a monitor is attached. The monitor displays “no signal” – as opposed to “no cable” when nothing is connected to it.

I use a passive DisplayPort→HDMI adapter (No name “DA050”). I have tried with two different devices, a TV and a monitor, with the same results. `nvidia-settings` only shows the internal display:

```
$ nvidia-settings -q ConnectedDisplays -d
Attribute 'ConnectedDisplays' (hostname:0.0): DFP-0.
```

The graphical version of `nvidia-settings` also shows no reaction when pressing the »Detect Displays« button.

A different laptop is able to output HDMI to the monitor using the same cable. VGA output with a dual-screen setup works fine. I have tried cold booting both with the monitor attached and disconnected. I don’t have another DisplayPort device to check whether the adapter works.

**Does this combination of hardware generally work in Linux?** Is there any option to the Nvidia driver to force output to the DisplayPort? Anything else I could try?

---

Update: It doesn’t work in Windows 7 with current Nvidia drivers (296.35), either.

Comment: The Thinkpad W520's displayport is a ++DP port (dual mode Displayport) so is capable of single link DVI/HDMI output with a passive adapter. So it's a software or cable issue.

Comment: I have almost the same problem on similar setup t420s (nvidia nvs 4200m). Displayport not working on deepin os, on elementary os I had only image, no sound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad adapter.

In the meantime I got a different Displayport-to-HDMI adapter. Video output works with the same laptop and monitor.

The software versions are now Linux 4.6 and Nvidia driver 361.45.18, just in case it was a driver issue after all.

I haven’t tried audio output.